# How to check if a file on a users computer matches the contents of a file on a webpage

Tags: python, web, key

I want to have a python script that will check and try and match the contents of a file on a users computer e.g /user/desktop/key/passkey.key with a link e.g. https://key.website.com and will continue on with the script If the files match, but stop if they don't.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KlausD. I have already figured out how to match files on the users local computer using the python OS module but I don't know how to compare a file on a local computer with a file that is stored on the web

Comment: Show us your code!